# Why is strcmp returning -1?

Tags: c, strcmp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char passage[5000][20];
char *getword(int i);

int main(){
    passage[0][0] = 'a';
    passage[0][1] = 'm';
    passage[0][2] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", getword(0));
    char *word = getword(0);
    printf("%d", strcmp(word,"am"));
    return 0;
}

char *getword(int i){             //get a word from passage
    int a=0;
    static char words[20];
    while (passage[i][a] != ' '){
        words[a] = passage[i][a];
        a++;
        //printf("%c\n",words[a]);
    }

    words[a] = '\0';

    return words;
}
```

I am planning to make a `function` for `string` comparing by getting a `string` from 2d `array` with the index and compare the `string` with some word. Why is the `strcmp` returning -1? It should be the same or did it take `null` into consideration as well?

Comment: for yr info, this will part of my big program, ihv asked a question be4
[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46794688/unable-to-return-array-from-a-function-to-do-passing

Comment: You should add `while (passage[i][a] != ' ' && a < 20)` to avoid go out of matrix bounds

Comment: Btw, we're assuming that every passage ends with `' '`, right?

Comment: I **assume** that this is [tag:c], correct? If you check the tag wiki for [tag:strcmp], you'll see that it's not *only* available in c. So please [edit] your question and add the appropriate language tag alongside the strcmp one.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (passage[i][a] != ' '){
```

change this to

```
while (passage[i][a] != '\0'){
```

Answer (score -3):

- string equal return 0
- first string is greater return 1
- second string is greater return -1

Comment: The question is "why does *this code* return -1", not "what does strcmp return in general".